# Can GraphicsMagick for Node.js process a non-fixed number of images to output a GIF sequence?

Tags: node.js, animated-gif, graphicsmagick

I'm using [GraphicsMagick for Node.js](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html) to generate a GIF sequence from 16 jpg images.
This works very well.
However currently I hardcoded the number of images in the sequence, when I use the function `gm().in`

I can't find a way or another function to make this number dynamic.

Here is my code:

```
var tmp_filenames = [];
var nNbStates = 16;

for (var nStateNum=0; nStateNum < nNbStates; nStateNum++)
{
    tmp_filenames.push('mypath\myinputfilename' + nStateNum + '.jpg');
}

var gm = require('gm');
gm()
.in(tmp_filenames[0])
.in(tmp_filenames[1])
.in(tmp_filenames[2])
.in(tmp_filenames[3])
.in(tmp_filenames[4])
.in(tmp_filenames[5])
.in(tmp_filenames[6])
.in(tmp_filenames[7])
.in(tmp_filenames[8])
.in(tmp_filenames[9])
.in(tmp_filenames[10])
.in(tmp_filenames[11])
.in(tmp_filenames[12])
.in(tmp_filenames[13])
.in(tmp_filenames[14])
.in(tmp_filenames[15])  
.write(output_filename, function (err) {
    if (!err) console.log('gif file created!');
});
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

OK I found a solution.
I was not familiar with this way of using variables and functions
This should work:

```
var tmp_filenames = [];
var nNbStates = 16;
var bmp = gm();

for (var nStateNum=0; nStateNum < nNbStates; nStateNum++)
{
    tmp_filenames.push('mypath\myinputfilename' + nStateNum + '.jpg');
    bmp.in(tmp_filenames[nStateNum])
}

.write(output_filename, function (err) {
    if (!err) console.log('gif file created!');
});
```